# Real Analysis, Folland Problem 5.3.32 The Baire Category Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, baire-category

> Problem 5.3.32 - Let $\lVert x \rVert_{1}$ and $\lVert x \rVert_{2}$ be norms on the vector space $\mathscr{X}$ such that $\lVert x \rVert_{1}\leq \lVert x \rVert_{2}$. If $\mathscr{X}$ is complete with respect to both norms, then the norms are equivalent.

I know that $0\in \mathscr{X}$ and also I know that the norms are equivalent if there exists a $C_1,C_2 > 0$ such that $$C_1\lVert x \rVert_{1} \leq \lVert x \rVert_{2} \leq C_2\lVert x \rVert_{1}$$ but I am not sure how to show this, any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1026438/equivalency-of-norms-and-the-open-mapping-theorem).

Comment: Thanks for the link but I am still pretty lost, I just want to know if there is another of proving it other than that method.

Comment: Do you want to prove it without the open mapping theorem?

Comment: I guess so maybe I do not understand the open mapping theorem well cause I don't know how it could be applied here.

Comment: Note that this exercise is in the section of the open mapping theorem. So, the open mapping theorem is probably supposed to be used in the expected solution.

Comment: Consider specifically the inclusion map $\mathscr H_1 \to \mathscr H_2$, from your compatibility condition this map is continuous. It is also a bijection. Now you can try to see how to apply the open mapping theorem.

Comment: In the answers of the linked post, they are using corollary 5.11 of Folland when they say "by the open mapping theorem".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have said, you have to prove that there exist $C_1,C_2 > 0$ such that $$C_1\lVert x \rVert_{1} \leq \lVert x \rVert_{2} \leq C_2\lVert x \rVert_{1}$$

By hypothesis, we have
$$C_1\lVert x \rVert_{1} \leq \lVert x \rVert_{2}\tag{1},$$
where $C_1=1$. So, it's enough to prove that there exists $C_2 > 0$ such that $$\lVert x \rVert_{2} \leq C_2\lVert x \rVert_{1}$$

In other words, you have to prove that the mapping $F:(\mathscr{X},\|\cdot\|_1)\to (\mathscr{X},\|\cdot\|_2)$ given by $F(x)=x$ is continuous.

Note that the mapping $F$ is the inverse of the mapping $T:(\mathscr{X},\|\cdot\|_2)\to (\mathscr{X},\|\cdot\|_1)$ given by $T(x)=x$.

Because of $(1)$, $T$ is continuous. So, by Corollary 5.11 of Folland, $F$ is continuous as desired.